# Should we adjusted the weight according to sample size in propensity score with IPTW method?

Tags: sas, propensity-scores, weighted-data

I'm a new learner in biostatistics, recently doing a project that might need to use IPTW method for balancing covariates between treatment groups.

When I read one of [the sas references](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/184-2007.pdf) [Ref 1] for IPTW, I was quite confused. It said we needed to adjust the weights according to the sample size of the treatment before we used it.

## ------------------------------------------------------------

[image: Adjusted Weight according to sample size]

## ------------------------------------------------------------

[Other tutorial material](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.6607/abstract) [Ref 2] about IPTW didn't mention that part at all.

**My questions:**

Should I re-adjust the weight according to the sample size of the treatment after calculating the inverse probability of treatment weight (IPTW) ?
Should I use the original IPTW to analyze the outcome models or just use the adjusted weight ?

Thanks a lot ~

[Ref 1] Scott Leslie et al, 2007,
[Using Propensity scores to adjust for treatment selection bias](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/184-2007.pdf)

[Ref 2]
Peter Austin,2015,
[Moving towards best practice when using (IPTW) using the propensity score to estimate causal treatment effects in observational studies](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.6607/abstract)

Comment: I have never seen this before, and it definitely won't do anything. Also, that code is incorrect for IPTW. The weights are 1/PS for the treated and 1/(1-PS) for the control. This is an important point!

Comment: Yes . I agree with the mis-coding for IPTW in the sas reference; 
W = z/e + (1-z) / (1-e) ....

However, after rethinking the questions, I do still consider re-modify the W according to sample size. The re-modify W according to sample size would not change the balance between covariates. 

Furthermore, since the sample size is inflated after weighting and the outcomes may turn to be easily significant, it may be appropriate to use the adjusted weight in the analyses. 
However, I think the adjusted weight wrote in the SAS Ref may not be corrected .